# Finding the random variable of socks?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> $2$ socks are selected at random and removed in succession from a drawer containing
>   $5$ brown socks and $3$ green socks. List the elements of the sample space, the
>   corresponding probabilities, and the corresponding values w of the random variable
>   W, where W is the number of brown socks selected.

In this problem their are

$8$ socks total , $5$ brown socks and $3$ green socks.

So I known one needs to find the Element of
sample space, Probability and w. What I am baffled about this question is how one derives these things.

If one removes a sock in succession that means you remove a sock one at a time.

So if you remove two brown socks in succession you should get

$$\Rightarrow \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} = \frac{5}{28}$$.

two green would be

$$\Rightarrow  \frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{2}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{56}$$

Yet this is not the correct procedure how does one interpret this correctly and derive the correct response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom 8 2$ ways to pick any two socks out of eight socks. For the first choice, you can pick any of the eight socks, but for the second pick, you can only pick seven socks. The probability that you pick two brown socks is $\frac 5 8 * \frac4 7$. The probability that you pick two green socks is $\frac 3 8 *\frac 2 7$. The probability of picking two different colored socks is one minus the two other probabilities.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying now the second sock you pull out decreases the number of socks their are. That is why it decreases I would have thought that once you pull out a sock it would show a notable decrease. I see my mistake.

Comment: Can you explain $w$ if you can?

Comment: $w$ might just be $\{0,1,2\}$.